# How to display a component at the end of a list

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

how would I go about displaying a component at the end of a list? Suppose that I have a list containing objects like below:

```js
items: [
      {name: 'Single Column', id: 1},
      {name: 'Double Columns', id: 2},
      {name: 'Triple Columns', id: 3},
      {name: 'Custom', id: 0}
    ],
```

Using a v-for to display the content of the list is straight forward (Note I'm using Vuetify here):

```html
<v-list>
    <v-list-item
        v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.id"
          link
          @click="setDashboardBluePrint(item)"
        >
        <v-list-item-title v-text="item.name"></v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

But suppose now that instead of the object `{name: 'Custom', id: 0}` for the last element in the items list, I want to have a button. And lets suppose that I already have a custom button component, `<Dialog/>` how would I go about displaying the `<Dialog/>` component in a stack, taking place of where `{name: 'Custom', id: 0}` would have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get all items but the last, and append another `v-list-item` in the template for the last item:

```html
<v-list>
    <v-list-item
        v-for="item in items.slice(0, items.length - 1)"
          :key="item.id"
          link
          @click="setDashboardBluePrint(item)"
        >
        <v-list-item-title v-text="item.name"></v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item>
    <v-list-item>
      <Dialog />
    </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```